# Importing Date into Snowflake tables

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a CSV file that I am trying to load into Snowflake manually.
I have created the tables and have the column type as DATETIME for the columns with dates.

The data is in the CSV is 20210709. This is getting imported into SNOWFLAKE as 1970-08-22

I cannot determine why that is.

I have another file with the date as 2/18/2022 and that is getting imported correctly.

Any help is appreciated

Sridhar

Comment: Check your date format in file format during load process and put date format  DATE_FORMAT = '<string>' as per your need and load data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved the issue as follows

1. Added a Date format (YYYMMDD) in the FILE FORMAT
2. Changed the column type as DATE instead of DATETIME.

Comment: How do I do that.  I do not see any option to CLOSE

Comment: Please, check this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved

Answer (score 2):

You should define the DATE_FORMAT parameter in the [FILE_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv) clause or when creating the [FILE FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html) object.

Example:

```sql
copy into mytable
  file_format = (type = 'CSV', DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD')
  pattern='.*/.*/.*[.]csv[.]gz';
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: `YYYYMMDD` is not a standard recognized date format, so you'll need to specify the format when parsing it.

Michael's answer is a great way to approach this, and I wanted to provide an alternative:

Here is some example syntax for specifying parsing and "transformations" per column during a COPY INTO import. [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html)

You'll need to have a stage established which can itself have parameters for file_format. [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html)

```sql
copy into mytable (date_col, second_column)
from (
    select TO_TIMESTAMP($1, 'YYYYMMDD'), $2
    from @mystage/filename.csv
)
```